# My Python multi-module package won't distribute with a py.typed file

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-packaging

I've created a package for Pip that contains multiple modules, which I am using for some other projects. On one of those projects, I recently added MyPy as Pylance was missing some potential errors, but when I import those modules, MyPy flags them as errors as they are missing a `py.typed` file. I have added one of these files to each submodule, so that the directory structure is as follows:

```
* MyRepo:
    * src
    |   * modulea
    |   |   * __init__.py
    |   |   * modulea.py
    |   |   * py.typed
    |   * moduleb
    |   |   * __init__.py
    |   |   * moduleb.py
    |   |   * py.typed
    * setup.cfg
```

I have also specified in `setup.cfg` to include package data, using the `include_package_data = True` flag.

```
[metadata]
# Other details

[options]
packages = find:
package_dir =
    =src
python_requires = >=3.9.1
include_package_data = True

[options.packages.find]
where = src
```

However when I distribute the package, it doesn't include any of the `py.typed` files. I have no idea why this is, and it's especially confusing considering that when I install it manually, using `pip install -e .`, I don't get any errors. I'd massively appreciate any help fixing this, as I am completely stumped.

Comment: Did my answer resolve your issue? If so, could you please accept it? If not, what was the error?

Comment: Sorry was busy with other things @JustinFuruness. I've accepted it now! I'd appreciate if you edited it to match the solution I found based on experimentation with your suggestion, so that it can be more helpful to others in the future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this is correct since I don't have the package in front of me but I'll take a crack at it.

I believe since py.typed is not a Python file, you need to specifically specify that you want to include it. For that, in your top level package, you need a [MANIFEST.in](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/using-manifest-in/). See the [MANIFEST.in](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/using-manifest-in/) link for the default files that are normally included by default in a package distribution - py.typed is not in there. In the MANIFEST.in file, you would write a line such as:

```
global-include py.typed
```

I believe include_package_data being set to true causes the package manager to look at the MANIFEST.in for any additional files that need to be distributed that are not python files.

I might also consider including and **init**.py in the src directory, and then just having one py.typed file there.

Comment: Thanks so much! I needed to add a `global-include py.typed` to it.

Comment: Edited to match your exact solution, thank you!